# IIS resets TLS handshake with nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, ssl, iis, sni

I am using 2 synchronized IIS servers (as backend for failover) and an nginx reverse proxy (as frontend).
Both IIS servers have identical configuration and websites (due to sync). All websites are under the same domain and I use ssl wildcard cert for all of them (*.example.com).

I have two different bindings for each site.

The first binding uses https and a unique port, different from the other sites. So, for example, site1 uses 4433 port, site2 uses 4434 port and so on..And it also uses the ssl wildcard certificate. And it looks like this:
[1st binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A44C2.png)

The second binding also uses https, the same ssl certificate BUT, is uses 443 port for every site. I use hostname and SNI for this binding and of course the same wildcard certificate.
So this binding looks like this:
[2nd binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkubn.png)

So, what's the problem?

When nginx proxies to the 1st binding (no hostname-sni and unique port)
everything works. However, when nginx proxies to the 2nd binding (hostname-sni using 443 port) web client gets a 502 and 504 error message. I use wireshark and what I see is that when nginx send the "client Hello" packet to start the TLS Handshake,
IIS replies with a "reset" packet, which terminates the communication.

I noticed that, when I uncheck the option "Require Server Name Indication", even on a website that is stopped, all websites work like a charm!
The second thing I noticed is that when my browser sends a http request DIRECTLY to IIS using the 2nd binding (443 port), even with SNI enabled, everything works!

Both nginx and IIS servers use TLSv1.2

Excuse me for the long post, but is there anyone who can help?

Comment: Given that the problem is in the interaction between nginx and IIS it is not enough to just provide how IIS was configured. You need to provide the configuration for nginx too. So far I can only speculate that you did not configure nginx properly to use the right SNI to the IIS or to use SNI at all. Check your configuration for `proxy_ssl_name` and `proxy_ssl_server_name`.

Comment: "I use wireshark and what I see is that when nginx send the "client Hello" packet to start the TLS Handshake", so what you missed is the host field as by default nginx does not send that out. However, SNI bindings do require that field to present. Like the other comment said, extra settings on nginx side can help.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich

Directives:
proxy_ssl_name $proxy_host;
proxy_ssl_server_name on;

did the trick! It crossed my mind that proxied packets did not "carry" server name but I'm new in nginx and reverse proxies in general so I was not sure what the issue could be and how to fix it! Thank you so much! Have a good day!